# Javascript With PHP - Dynamic Calls

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm new to web development, and I've never created anything too complex before. By which, I'm implying a complete website, I've usually just cross referenced post/json data with C# or Java. In any case, for a relatively large project, I've been asked to create a user management portal, and cutting more to the point, I'm currently stuck on the login form.

I know what to do, and how I'm going to go about managing user data and what not, but I'm trying to understand ajax. I wanted to slide out a notification for x-failed login attempts, and create a successful login message.

I tried to create a popup message to start off using php/js, but my attempt failed. This is essentially what I've got,

```
<?php

    function login() {
        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $driver = $_SESSION['driver'];
        if (isset($user) && isset($pass)) {

            if ($driver->login($user, $pass)) {

                echo('<script>window.alert(\'Success\');</script>');
            } else {

                echo('<script>window.alert(\'Failure\');</script>');
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

I know the login function works just fine, but the alert notification isn't appearing, instead bits of the code appear on the web-page after executed, which shouldn't be occurring seeing as to it's a script-call.

Any input/insight would be very helpful, and thank you for taking the time to read my thread.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `()` for the echo just used `''` like this

`echo '<script>alert("Success");</script>';`

Comment: Just a note to add, the reason for not needing parentheses is because echo is a language construct, and not a function.